# Make wildcard dependency No rule to make target needed by

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build my targets with wildcards.  Here is my Makefile:

```
BINARY      = main
LDSCRIPT    = stm32f4-discovery.ld

PREFIX     ?= arm-none-eabi
CC          = $(PREFIX)-gcc
LD          = $(PREFIX)-gcc
OBJCOPY     = $(PREFIX)-objcopy

CFLAGS      += -Os -g \
       -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration \
       -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
       -Wundef -Wshadow \
       -I$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/include \
       -fno-common -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb \
       -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MD -DSTM32F4
LDSCRIPT    ?= $(BINARY).ld
LDFLAGS     += --static -lc -lnosys -L$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/lib \
       -L$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/lib/stm32/f4 \
       -T$(LDSCRIPT) -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections \
       -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
OBJS        += $(BINARY).o

all: images

images: $(BINARY).images

%.images: %.bin
    @#printf "*** $* images generated ***\n"

%.bin: %.elf
    @#printf "  OBJCOPY $(*).bin\n"
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -Obinary $(*).elf $(*).bin

%.elf: $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPT) $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/lib/libopencm3_stm32f4.a
    @#printf "  LD      $(subst $(shell pwd)/,,$(@))\n"
    $(Q)$(LD) -o $(*).elf $(OBJS) -lopencm3_stm32f4 $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c Makefile
    @#printf "  CC      $(subst $(shell pwd)/,,$(@))\n"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    $(Q)rm -f *.o
    $(Q)rm -f *.d
    $(Q)rm -f *.elf
    $(Q)rm -f *.bin

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

When I make, I get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `main.bin', needed by `main.images'.  Stop.
```

I am trying to make a single image, so I can change each `%` to `$(BINARY)`, and this works, but I would like to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You'll have to run `make -d` and follow the logic to see why make gives up on the implicit rule search.  Most likely some prerequisite is not considered creatable by make.  However, if you change the `%` to `$(BINARY)` and it works that's odd, because I'd expect it would give you an error that it can't build some file or other.

Comment: is `TOOLCHAIN_DIR` set? does `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/lib/libopencm3_stm32f4.a` exist? does `stm32f4-discovery.ld` exist in the current directory?

Comment: @ComeRaczy, yes to all.

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem? If so: how?!

Answer (score 1):

You are *likely* missing a dependency somewhere down the chain.

Note: Some people forget that the "Makefile" itself, when placed on the dependency line - is also checked for existance. Double check that you haven't renamed it.

Like @MadScientist recommends, "make -d" will be your friend here. Use that to locate the rule/file that should have been found but was not.

I simplified your example (on Linux) and got the same type of error with:

**Makefile:**

```
all: main.out
%.out: %.elf
   g++ $^ -o $@
%.elf: %.obj
   mv $^ $@
%.obj: %.cpp Makefile
   g++ -c $^ -o $@
```

Create main.cpp, see it work, then rename main.cpp to something else that it can't find, run again, see it fail.

Now rename the Makefile itself, see the same failure.